# PostgreSQL : How do I take multiple rows with values in different columns and combine into one row with all the values on one line?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, amazon-redshift, navicat

This is the table I have currently. 
I would like to combine everything as one event_code and have everything in one line. I checked stack and google and got different answers which doesn't seem to solve my issue.

[image: What I have now]

What I would like to have is

```
**event_code : fs_rev : hs_rev :  pp_rev :   mp_rev : gp_rev :  in_rev : broker**

LAK180918  :  619500  :   0    :  7000   :    0     :   5000  :   8500  :   17500
```

I can't seem to find the answer on how to do this, by combining all the columns under one row. Can anyone suggest what i should do?

Comment: is this postgres or redshift? they are NOT the same at all. please edit question/tags accordingly.

Comment: please describe the rule/logic for example why is pp_rev =5000 do you want the FIRST non null value?

Comment: I'm using postgresql and was told that it's hooked up to aws-redshift. Also, if you look at the data, the event_code for pp_rev is different, so 918 should have 7000 whereas 920 should have 58000. I wanted all the rows to be crunched into one

Comment: to be 100% clear you are EITHER using redshift or you are using postgres, and they are different. no matter what you have been told this is the case! I see what you mean about the event code being different. so your requirement is to get the highest value if there are 2 or more within an event code?

Comment: It's a Navicat software connected to amazon redshift which uses postgresql on my end, as far as I know. The requirement was to get one row with the values showing one for each column. As you can see each row has one column with a value while rest are null, and I needed this all crunched up into one row

Comment: Just to be clear, believe it or not, its not postgres you are using, its redshift. try using some postgres features mentioned as not supported like indexes (create an index) and you will soon find out! see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Max or Min function. I am assuming you will have only one valid value for each column in the event.

```
select event_code, max(fs_rev),max(hs_rev),max(pp_rev),max(mp_rev)
,max(gp_rev),max(in_rev),max(broker)
from table
group by event_code
```

Comment: Thank you. I feel like an idiot now not seeing such a simple solution. This took care of it